# What is the time complexity of this code Union Of two Arrays using set_union?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, set

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n, m;
        cin >> n >> m;
        vector<int> v1(n);
        vector<int> v2(m);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> v1[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            cin >> v2[i];
        }
        set<int> s1(v1.begin(),v1.end());
        set<int> s2(v2.begin(), v2.end());
        set<int> s3;
        set_union(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), inserter(s3, s3.begin()));
        for (auto i : s3) cout << i;
    }
}
```

This code takes two vectors and unions them?
Eg: if the input is 5,4,3,2,1 and 5,4,6
Output will be 1,2,3,4,5,6

I am confused about its time complexity? What is time complexity of creation of a set from a vector? What is time complexity of using set_union function?

Comment: set_union assumes sorted arrays - which is not guaranteed in your example. with this assumption it's linear complexity O(N+M) where N and M are the sizes of the arrays.

Comment: @StPiere It is actually guaranteed that these are sorted arrays as this is an unordered set, so it gets sorted automatically when inserted(i dont know how, if u can explain this too) . OK so time complexity of this line set<int> s1(v1.begin(),v1.end());  is linear?? because what i have read insertions in a set taken O(logn) because it is implemented with help of RB tree.

Comment: ah sorry - overseen that your are using set. but just a notion: you can also work with vector instead of set, if you sort the vector(s) first

Comment: @StPiere Can u please read the edited comment!! but if i use vector and then sort, time complexity would be O(nlogn)

Comment: Constructing the set from vector also has N*log(N) complexity (if the vector is not sorted already - otherwise is set constructing linear complexity). Eitherway you end up with total complexity of N*log(N) to sort (directly or via inserting into set)  and then linear complexity for union.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are using `std::set`'s. In the C++ standard library, unfortunately, `std::set`'s are *ordered* (and we have `std::unordered_set`). Thus, most of the "hard work" in your code is actually converting the vectors into ordered sets; that takes O(n log(n) + m log(m)) time. The union is - almost certainly - linear, as @StPiere suggests, so an additional O(n+m) time.